# How to convert observable of array of observables of data into observable of an array of data

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner, doing my Ionic project with Firebase Firestore.
There will be two types of client, group A and group B.
It is a social media application which people from A can be friend people from B and vice versa, but not from the same group.

As I'm querying the data for user from group A, there will be connected users in group B in the user's data.

So my code is like in the form of:

```
this.items = this.firestore.collection<Data>('a_users',ref => ref.where('UID','==',getUID()).valueChanges().map(
  users => users[0].conn.map(conn_id => {
    return this.firestore.collection<Data>('b_users', ref => ref.where('UID','==',conn_id)).valueChanges().map(b => b[0]);
  })
)
```

It will return `Observable<Observable<Data>[]>` but when I tried to display in an `ion-list` in HTML using `async` pipe, the result is `#undefined`.

The goal is to display the above data properly (with an immediate response when an item changes) in an `ion-list`.

Answer (score 0):

Think you have to use async pipe twice in order to map to data change

```
this.items = this.firestore.collection<Data>('a_users',ref => ref.where('UID','==',getUID()).valueChanges().map(
  users =>users[0].conn.map(conn_id => {
    return this.firestore.collection<Data>('b_users', ref => ref.where('UID','==',conn_id)).valueChanges().map(b => b[0]);
  })
)
```

html

```
  <ion-list *ngFor="let user of users | async"> 
     <strong> {user.props | async}</strong>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: The second `map` cannot be changed to `flatMap` because `users[0].conn` a normal array.

Comment: so you want to flatten users[0].conn as an array of observables?

Comment: No, I want to achieve the return value of `Observable<Data[]>`.

Comment: updated the answer, to produce a flat observable is less efficient in your use case imho

Comment: You can try slice the functions up into two smaller function in order to debug. 1st start with `this.firestore.collection<Data>('a_users',ref => ref.where('UID','==',getUID()).valueChanges().map(
  users =>users[0].conn)` , see if you get any result.